# How can I make return value in "for loop method" an array instead of lists?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example:

```js
for (let i = 7; i <= 43; i += 7) {

  if (i < 40) i -= 2;

  console.log(i);

};


/**but I want [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 42] as my output value. I want array instead of lists how can I achieve that?**/
```

---

What I am trying to get is an Array output from the "for loop method"
above or how to converts the output of that loop to a single array.

Comment: What do you mean by " the array method "?

Comment: [ 5, 10, 15] is an array.

Comment: You need a function to return a value. A loop can't return. What do you mean with _"lists"_? There are no lists in JavaScript.

Comment: Using `indexOf` inside a `for` loop will give you `O( n * m )` or `O( n^2 )` performance. Don't do that.

Comment: @ThomasSablik If it's a generator function...

Comment: what i want is to convert the output value of that loop to a single array.  can you help with that

Comment: @Dai Can you finish your comment? It makes no sense for me. You can't return a value without function. A generator function is a function.

Comment: can you check again now @ Thomas

Comment: What do you mean with _"for loop method"_? Do you mean the for loop? You should remove the words "return" and "lists" from you question or add a function. What's wrong with the two answers?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a list in JavaScript, there is simply an array.

```js
function countNumbers() {
  let data = [];
  
  for (let i = 7; i <= 43; i += 7) {
    if (i < 40) i -= 2;
    data.push(i);
  };
  return data;
}

console.log(countNumbers());

/**but I want [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 42] as my return value. I want array instead of lists how can I achieve that?**/
```

Comment: wow! Thank you I have my answer now

Comment: good luck and be done